# Error related 'ember-cli-live-reload.js' is missing (not loading) while using Express server

Tags: express, angular, ember-cli, angular-cli, angular2-cli

I'm getting the following error while using Express server to serve content generated by the Angular-CLI sample app.:

http://localhost:4200/ember-cli-live-reload.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

OS: Windows 7

Versions:

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10
node: 5.11.1
os: win32 x64
express: 4.13.4
Repro steps:

After accessing the URL after starting the app using ng serve or node server.js, this error appears in the Chrome Developer Toolbar:
`http://localhost:4200/ember-cli-live-reload.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

This exception in the console:
TypeError: res.status is not a function at C:\xxxx\server.js:43:7 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xxxx\node_modules\express\li b\router\layer.js:95:5) at trim_prefix (C:\xxxx\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312 :13) at C:\xxxx\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7 at Function.process_params (C:\xxxx\node_modules\express\lib\router\ index.js:330:12) at next (C:\xxxx\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10) at SendStream.error (C:\xxxx\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:

Any workaround or a fix for this issue? Has anyone tried using Express on the Angular-CLI?

Comment: I commeted out the script tag in the index.html and it works so far :-)